# How to retrieve a tree of objects from a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a calculation that I'd like to do in a stored procedure, which includes some aggregations, to reduce the amount of data sent back to the caller. Given the structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Parent
(
    ParentID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    A1 int NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Child
(
    ChildID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID int NOT NULL,
    Expected int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Child_Parent FOREIGN KEY (ParentID) REFERENCES Parent (ParentID)
)

CREATE TABLE Grandchild
(
    GrandchildID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ChildID int NOT NULL,
    Actual int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_Grandchild_Child FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES Child (ChildID)
)
```

and the stored procedure

```sql
CREATE PROC testCounts AS
WITH TotalActual AS
(
    SELECT ChildID, SUM(Actual) AS Actual
    FROM Grandchild
    GROUP BY ChildID
)
SELECT ParentID, A1, ChildID, Expected - SUM(Actual) AS Variance
FROM Parent
INNER JOIN Child ON Parent.ParentID = Child.ParentID
INNER JOIN TotalActual ON Child.ChildID = TotalActual.ChildID
```

What I'd like to be able to do is create a tree of objects of type `Parent` containing many `ChildVariance` objects. Is Entity Framework able to do this?

So far I've defined:

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        ChildVariances = new HashSet<ChildVariance>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public int A1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChildVariance> ChildVariances { get; set; }
}

public class ChildVariance
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }

    public int Variance { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

// In my dbContext
public virtual DbSet<Parent> Parents { get; set; }    

override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>
        .HasMany(e => e.ChildVariances)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Parent)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);
}

// In an access method

var results = Parents.SqlQuery("testCounts");
```

Examining `results`, I get back the number of parent rows multiplied by the child rows. There are no entries in the `Parent` object's `Childs` collection.

Doing it this way, I get proxy objects. That is, the debugger shows the class name as `{System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Parent_C553E08E8B955294BB6673459018EE9B5A7FCB3DF260DEC0B7A10621F4560409}`. If instead I make the `Parent` and `ChildVariance` classes `sealed`, I don't get the proxy objects, but it still doesn't work.

Can Entity Framework actually construct a tree of objects from a single resultset in this way? If so, how do I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't fully answer the question, but I was able to solve my actual problem by using a **view** rather than a **stored procedure**. I didn't need multiple query steps, just a single query.

```sql
CREATE VIEW ChildVariance AS
WITH TotalActual AS
(
    SELECT ChildID, SUM(Actual) AS Actual
    FROM Grandchild
    GROUP BY ChildID
)
SELECT ParentID, ChildID, Expected, Expected - SUM(Actual) AS Variance
FROM Child
INNER JOIN TotalActual ON Child.ChildID = TotalActual.ChildID
```

I can then map `ChildVariance` as if it were a table:

```
public class ChildVariance
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }

    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    public int Expected { get; set; }
    public int Variance { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent;
}
```

Then I just access the `Parent.ChildVariances` navigation property to load the data. To get them both retrieved in the same batch, I can just add `.Include("ChildVariances")` to the query.